# Reading CSV file from stdin in Python and modifying it

Tags: python, csv

I need to read csv file from stdin and output the rows only the rows which values are equal to those specified in the columns. My input is like this:

```
 2
 Kashiwa
 Name,Campus,LabName
 Shinichi MORISHITA,Kashiwa,Laboratory of Omics
 Kenta Naai,Shirogane,Laboratory of Functional Analysis in Silico
 Kiyoshi ASAI,Kashiwa,Laboratory of Genome Informatics
 Yukihide Tomari,Yayoi,Laboratory of RNA Function
```

My output should be like this:

```
 Name,Campus,LabName
 Shinichi MORISHITA,Kashiwa,Laboratory of Omics
 Kiyoshi ASAI,Kashiwa,Laboratory of Genome Informatics
```

I need to sort out the people whose values in column#2 == Kashiwa and not output first 2 lines of stdin in stdout.

So far I just tried to read from stdin into csv but I am getting each row as a list of strings (as expected from csv documentation). Can I change this?

```
 #!usr/bin/env python3

 import sys
 import csv

 data = sys.stdin.readlines()

 for line in csv.reader(data):

      print(line)
```

Output:

```
 ['2']
 ['Kashiwa']
 ['Name', 'Campus', 'LabName']
 ['Shinichi MORISHITA', 'Kashiwa', 'Laboratory of Omics']
 ['Kenta Naai', 'Shirogane', 'Laboratory of Functional Analysis in 
 Silico']
 ['Kiyoshi ASAI', 'Kashiwa', 'Laboratory of Genome Informatics']
 ['Yukihide Tomari', 'Yayoi', 'Laboratory of RNA Function']
```

Can someone give me some advice on reading stdin into CSV and manipulating the data later (outputting only needed values of columns, swapping the columns, etc.,)?

Comment: maybe [DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) ?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import csv

data = sys.stdin.readlines()  # to read the file
column_to_be_matched = int(data.pop(0)) # to get the column number to match
word_to_be_matched = data.pop(0) # to get the word to be matched in said column
col_headers = data.pop(0) # to get the column names
print(", ".join(col_headers)) # to print the column names
for line in csv.reader(data):
    if line[column_to_be_matched-1] == word_to_be_matched: #while it matched
        print(", ".join(line)) #print it
```

Comment: Do not use `readlines` for reading CSV files. There might be new lines within a single cell.

Answer (score 1):

Use Pandas to read your and manage your data in a DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
# File location
infile = r'path/file'
# Load file and skip first two rows
df = pd.read_csv(infile, skiprows=2)
# Refresh your Dataframe en throw out the rows that contain Kashiwa in the campus column
df = df[df['campus'] != 'Kashiwa']
```

You can perform all kinds edits for example sort your DataFrame simply by:

```
df.sort(columns='your column')
```

Check the [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html) for all the possibilities.

Comment: thanks a lot. Also one more question. The grader shows me the error with this note: "In addition, special characters such as "," or "" "and line feed are not included in the name etc. You can think of it as plain CSV." How do I delete these characters in my csv?

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
import csv

with open(filename) as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(reader) #Skip First Line
    next(reader) #Skip Second Line
    print(next(reader)) #print Header
    for row in reader:
        if row[1] == 'Kashiwa':   #Filter By 'Kashiwa'
            print(row)
```

**Output:**

```
['Name', 'Campus', 'LabName']
['Shinichi MORISHITA', 'Kashiwa', 'Laboratory of Omics']
['Kiyoshi ASAI', 'Kashiwa', 'Laboratory of Genome Informatics']
```

Comment: Is there a way to change data type of output and from list of strings change to strings separated by commas? It should be like this:                            
       Name,Campus,LabName
       Shinichi MORISHITA,Kashiwa,Laboratory of Omics
       Kiyoshi ASAI,Kashiwa,Laboratory of Genome Informatics

Comment: My input is not from the file but rather lines from stdin so reader does not work for it

Comment: But you have `csv.reader(data):` in your code...is that not working? Note: You do not have to use `with open(filename) as csv_file:` I just added it as a demo code

Comment: However, when I am using it now with next(), it shows me an error: next(reader)
StopIteration

Comment: thanks so much for your help. Last question. How do I also delete white spaces between consecutive strings in the output? To make it not Name, Campus, LabName but Name,Campus,LabName

Comment: sorry once again. The grader shows me the error with this note: "In addition, special characters such as "," or "" "and line feed are not included in the name etc. You can think of it as plain CSV." How do I delete these characters in my csv?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193680/discussion-between-dari-obukhova-and-rakesh).

Answer (score 0):

```
    import csv, sys

    f= sys.stdin.readline()
    data = csv.reader(f)

    out = []
    data_lines = list(data)
    for line in data_lines[2:5]:#u can increase index to match urs
        if line[1] == 'kashiwa':
            new = [line[0], line[1], line[2]]#u can use string instead if list
            string = f"{line[0]},{line[1]},{line[2]}"
            #print(string)#print does same as stdout u can use dis
            sys.stdout.write(string+'\n')
            out.append(new)

    sys.stdout.write(str(out))#same thing dat happens in print in the background#it out puts it as a list after the string repr

    #print(out)#u can use dis too instead of stdout

    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a cleaner way making a unix-style csv transform, while letting the csv module decide on quoting:

```
import csv, sys

rows = csv.reader(sys.stdin)
out = csv.writer(sys.stdout, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

for row in rows:
   # do something here -- modify row, or continue to skip this row, etc
   out.writerow(row)
```